# Identifying resources of REST endpoints for given context

Tags: rest

I am having trouble naming rest endpoints for my otp service.

Here I have 4 endpoints, in brackets I have given inputs

1. SEND API (Mo. No.) - Generates OTP and send to mobile number, in response it gives TransactionId
2. RESEND API (TransId) - Resend same OTP to mobile Number with the transactionId
3. VERIFY API (OTP, TransId)- Verify if the OTP given for the transactionId, is correct to what is stored in cache
4. ISVERIFIED API (TransId) - Check whether particular transactionId is verified or not

Can anyone please tell me how should I make REST endpoints for these APIs, adhere-ring to REST principles of resources, etc.

I thought of

1. POST v1/sendOTP
2. POST v1/resendOTP
3. POST v1/verifyOTP
4. POST v1/isVerifiedTransaction

Obviously, this is not a good design of endpoints, I need some help

Comment: What is your question, exactly ?

Comment: /send, /resend, /verify, /is-verified

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question.

Comment: @datdinhquoc, all of these should be POST requests?

Comment: yes, POST should do it all

Comment: @admin What can I do to improve the score of this question?

Comment: @OnurA. I am extremely sorry for posting the question without enough information on the first place. I have updated it later. The question about identifying proper resources of REST endpoints for the context I have given.

Comment: @prakharjain no worries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach would be

```
POST v1/send-otp
POST v1/resend-otp
POST v1/verify-otp
```

POST v1/is-verified-transaction if you have to make the separate endpoint for each

else as these can be part of the same end-point only the payload can be different, you cna do something like

```
POST v1/otp?action=send
POST v1/otp?action=re-send
POST v1/otp?action=verify
POST v1/is-verified-transaction or v1/transaction?status=is-verified
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have `otp` and `transaction` as resources and do something like this:

```
POST v1/otp/send
POST v1/transaction/{transId}/resend
GET v1/transaction/{transactionId}/verify?otp={otpId}
GET v1/transaction/{trandId}/isVerified
```

I am not sure how otp and transactions relate, so it might be a bit off, just throwing the idea of having them as resources